# Animation node - circle generator inside loop

Tags: animation-nodes

Anyone know why these shapes all have the same diameter - I was expecting them to get bigger for each iteration...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to replace the mesh anyway, I suggest going with a simple mesh instance (uncheck "Copy from source") in the "Object Instancer" node.

But I don't know why your solution doesn't behave properly honestly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that was the answer - unchecking "Copy from source" gave me exactly what I wanted.